# How to pass List<ABC> to WCF test client

Tags: wcf, wcftestclient

I have `DataContract` as below

```
[DataContract]
    public class Test
    {
        public List<Validation> val { get; set; }
    }
```

and my `OperationContract` as below

```
public bool TestValidation(Test t, out string message)
        {
            return ValidationUtility.ValidateFields(t.val, out message);
        }
```

I am not getting how to set value for Test.val on `WCF Test Client`

[image]

Comment: you're not able to edit the values for datacontract using test client?

Comment: can you show us what happens after you expand objvalidation?

Comment: its already expanded :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it seems like you're missing the `DataMember` attribute for your list.

```
[DataContract]
public class Test {
    [DataMember]
    public List <Validation> val { get; set; }
}
```

Also, ensure that the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes for `Validation` are set up properly as well. Then restart your WCF Test Client and try calling the service again.

Expand the `objvalidation` part on the Name column. A + sign should appear next to the request parameter name. You can then add elements and fill out their properties (Value column) by expanding each individual element you've added.